# Clear opacity in d3 after click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class",                     "slice");

        arcs.append("svg:path")
             .on("click", function(d) {//clicking on individual arcs 
                arcs.style("opacity", 1);
                d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.7);
```

So I have a pie chart in which when I click on an individual arc, its opacity will go down to 0.7. However, I want the opacity to go back to 1 when I click on another arc. This code right now is not working. The opacity of any previous arcs clicked are persisting whenever I click on new arcs.

Comment: In your click handler, replace `arcs` with `vis.selectAll("g.slice")`.

Comment: Hmm that still doesn't work, the previous arcs clicked still have its opacity at 0.7. The opacity is still not resetting to 1.

Comment: Make that `arcs.selectAll("path")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending a `path` element to your `g` elements and setting the opacity on that. So in the click handler, you have to select those again:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
            arcs.selectAll("path").style("opacity", 1);
            d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.7);
})
```